# get keyof class from array of string

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I have an array of string, that is dynamic, not a const.

this array contains somes name of property of a class

```
export class MyClass {
    name: string,
    surname: string 
}
```

i want a function that return a keyof this array such as

```
getKeyOf(columns: string[]): (keyof MyClass)[] {
...
}
```

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=15&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/LAKAxgNghgzjAEBZAngYWneBvU8-wDsoBbAUwC54YAXAJwEsCBzeAXngCIPd8YBXWkTKUaDZm07cQAX1CgwAewI14jGlAJhSEgqQDuSNBhgBuUADM+m6vSXwmpagGlSyAPLmAFIoh9iykTpGJgBtAF0ASkpPAGtXBXNDdFgYCPDsHjxaRwECeB8-ZQA6c3oIalJabzYAPnzVPLVqDS0I+Fh4WPjElGS4NLCzGTlwJRU45AR2B2dXD08QjiFSDgAaTn5BEhX1jgVqAAtKjkih+TGFCFIiiAUmLsmI0CA)?

Comment: thank you, i started from your example, but it's simpler then the code.
I have to cast to (keyof MyClass)[] the array